# Why would labels generate NA for scale_y_continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:100, y=1:100)) +
       geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
       scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 189), labels=function(x) {print(x);x} )
[1]   0  50 100 150 NA
```

When I tried to customize labels function, I didn't handle `NA`, which resulted in an error.

After investigation, I see sometimes labels would generate `NA`, though it is not displayed in the plot.

When is `NA` generated? Why is `NA` generated?

I tried `pretty(c(0,189)) # [1]   0  50 100 150 200`, it doesn't output `NA`

#### Update

Alright, I believe it is because the values generated by `pretty` always cover the range of `x`, so that the min, max values are outside the plotting range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens in subtle, but a very common mistake in ggplot.

When you use a `scale_*` command to limit the sample space, it disallows data outside those limits from being used in any functions.  Hence, why your function returns `NA` when the limit is set to 189.

Instead of limiting the scale with `scale_y_continuous`, try `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 189))`.

This will perserve the full data set, even though only the portion set by the limit in `coord_cartesian` will be shown.

Like this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:100, y=1:100)) +
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 50)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 50)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200), ylim = c(0, 200))
```

Comment: But what I don't understand is that neither value in 1:100 fall outside of those limits why does it turn any value to NA in this case? What am I missing...